# Fedora 39 freezing on waking from suspend *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000900] Flip event timeout on head 0

Tags: fedora, nvidia, suspend, wayland

Fedora Workstation 39 is freezing on waking up from suspend.

It doesn't freeze when using x11, only when using wayland display server.

I have NVIDIA driver version 545, some forums told me this could be because of firefox, but it turned out not to be true, but i'm still putting that tag here for people to find.

I found this error in my `journalctl --boot=-1`:

```
[drm:nv_drm_atomic_commit [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000900] Flip event timeout on head 0
```

but i'm not completely sure that it's related.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the nvidia driver from version 545 to 535 solved my problem with freezing from suspend.

Applying this command and rebooting was enough:

```
sudo dnf downgrade "*nvidia*" --allowerasing
reboot
```

Switching to x11 when logging in also seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Instead of downgrading set `nvidia_drm modeset=1 fbdev=0`